# Retrieve a variable from another class

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing

I have two classes, how can I pass the pathentry variable to the next class? Essentially the pathentry variable is a pathname to a file that is entered in a text entry.

```
class LabelBrowseButtonWidget(AbsLabelInputWidget):
        """Class created to create button widgets in the header of the gui"""

    def create_input(self):
        filepath_var = StringVar()
        self.Button = ttk.Button(self,
                                 text="Select Input File",
                                 command=lambda: filepath_var.set(self.getFilePath())
                                 )
        self.Button.pack(fil=tk.X, padx=0, expand=True)

        pathentry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=filepath_var)
        pathentry.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, expand=False)

        return pathentry

    def getFilePath(self):
        filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Excel Files", "*.xls"),
                                                         ("Excel Files", "*.xlsx")))
        return filepath

class LabelButtonWidget(AbsLabelInputWidget):
    """Button created for executing the import of the input file"""

    def create_input(self, *args):
        self.Button = ttk.Button(self,
                                 text="Import Input File",
                                 command=lambda: self.fileImport()
                                 )
        self.Button.pack(fil=tk.X, padx=5, expand=True)

    def fileImport(self):
        pathentry = LabelBrowseButtonWidget.create_input(self.pathentry.get())
        print(pathentry)
        # print("now what?")
```

I think I am a little lost here.

Comment: Where is the problem? In the `def fileImport` or `LabelButtonWidget`?

Comment: I need to pass the text in the path entry widget in the LabelbrowseButtonwidget class to the fileImport in the Label Button widget. Is that easy to do? How would I be able to tell where the problem is to answer your question? sorry, still a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand.

**Do you want to have a variable accessible from everywhere?** If so, use `global`. When defining a variable, first put this line:

global variable
And then before you access it.

**Do you want to pass a variable to a class when you create an instance of it?** If so use the `__init__` function:

```
class classname(object):
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.variable=variable
```

Then when you create the instance:

```
instance=classname(variable)
```

And to access the variable from within the class:

```
self.variable
```

And from outside:

```
instance.variable
```

**Or do you just want to retrieve a variable that is an attribute of a different class?** If so:

```
instance.variable
```